# SQL latest changes

Tags: sql

I need the latest changes made to FIELD_NAME col. for example below, under col key_2, 3332P6; Field_Name 'Submission', was modified 3 times within my extract date. although not duplicate i need just the latest modification which is UNIQUE_RID 47271398. is that possible?

[image]

```
select Key_2,
       LEFT (REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 4) PROJECT_CODE,
       (CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''))  >4 THEN RIGHT(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 2)    ELSE ''
        END as PROJECT_PHASE,

        FIELD_NAME, AUDIT_OLD_VALUE, AUDIT_NEW_VALUE,
        UNIQUE_RID, AUDIT_DATE, AUDIT_TIME

 FROM TBADT_AUDIT_TRAIL 
 WHERE Key_1 like 'WKSCHART' AND
       Audit_Date between '2017-06-13' and '2017-06-16'
 ORDER BY Key_2, FIELD_NAME
```

I know that it works in VBA but I'm fairly new to SQL. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Mcirosoft SQL  server 2008.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i put an image for sample purposes and didn't know how else to attach my result set.